# UWP app with and without Fluent Design System (dependent on the version of Windows 10)

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, fluent-design

I am develop a new UWP app and I want this new app to have a Fluent Design System in the supported versions (Creators Update and Fall Creators Update), but I also want previous versions of Windows 10 also to have access to the app but without the Fluent Design System.

It is possible? If yes, how?

Is there any tutorial to explain this?

Comment: Set min version e.g 10.0.10240 and target version to you 10.0.16299 fall creator updatw

Comment: on [14393 I also see Fluent Design in the app myTube Beta](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AtziW2MYxY8SlLI1f0PApE31wYROPQ) and I think Th2 1511 no longer gets updates, so all current Win10m version (1607, 1703, 1709 Feature2) can have some kind of glass. So use the Version adaptive code to see at runtime which API is available and which not.

Comment: @ShubhamSahu but that does not solve my problem :(

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you very much! How adaptive code works?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are targeting a minimum version older than `Creators Update`, you cannot utilize the recently introduced [Conditional XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml).

You're essentially limited to implement [Version adaptive code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code)
, which has the drawback of allowing the setting of certain properties/ instantiation objects depending on the OS version, only in `code behind`, rather than in `markup`.

Comment: How Conditional XAML works? Can you give me an example for my case, please? Thank you!

Comment: @fernandousaaa take a look at the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/conditional-xaml

Comment: @Rafael thank you, but I had seen this, but I still do not understand how it works and how I should use it in my case

Comment: @fernandousaaa conditional XAML allows you to specify properties and values based on the Universal API contract. Example, Prop1 exists in latest windows (contract version 5) but not in the prev one (v4) so using conditional XAML you can tell XAML engine to only set the property if it is running on contract 5. if it is on contract 4 the XAML engine won't set the property and so no exceptions will be thrown.